# Cannot find module 'cli-cursor' vue-cli

Tags: vue.js

i installed vue-cli
but when i run

> vue create -f name

i get this error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cli-cursor'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mrkinix\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\list.js:9:17)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
PS D:\New folder>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `cli-cursor` globally using `npm` or `yarn`:

```
$ npm install -g cli-cursor
or,
$ yarn global add cli-cursor
```

Comment: i got this :         "
npm notice save cli-cursor is being moved from dependencies to devDependencies
npm WARN new-folder@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN new-folder@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ cli-cursor@2.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 10 packages in 2.558s
found 0 vulnerabilities "          

and then when i run the command i still get the same error

Comment: Maybe, `cli-cursor` should be kept in dependencies.. can you try removing `node_modules`? `rm -rf node_modules; npm install`

Comment: does `cli-cursor` module exist inside `node_modules/`?

Comment: D:.
└───node_modules
    ├───cli-cursor
    ├───mimic-fn
    ├───onetime
    ├───restore-cursor
    ├───signal-exit
    └───vue-router
        ├───dist
        └───types

Comment: try installing `cli-cursor` globally: `npm install -g cli-cursor`